# Selenium Python: Hidden Input Field Not Interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on selenium python (modifying zap auth repo) trying to pass login page that has hidden field for the password. So the login flow would be, **Insert Email** > **Click Button "Continue"** > **(password field comes up)** **Insert Password** > **Click Button "Login"**. Each button has different button id and this flow **working on the same page**.

I've tried using actionchain, find_element and execute_script to fill the field as well, but seems not found any solutions.

here's my part of code

```
if self.config.auth_password:
            try:
                # ActionChains(self.driver).click("Continue").perform()
                self.fill_password()
            except Exception:
                logging.warning(
                    'Did not find the password field - clicking Next button and trying again')
                button = self.driver.find_element_by_id("Continue")
                button.click()
                # if the password field was not found, we probably need to submit to go to the password page
                # login flow: username -> next -> password -> submit
                self.fill_password()
```

This code always returning `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`, seems like ignoring the button click before.

This code returning

```
2022-12-16 18:42:21,099 Found element password by name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/zap/zap_auth.py", line 203, in login
    self.fill_password()
  File "/zap/zap_auth.py", line 262, in fill_password
    return self.find_and_fill_element(self.config.auth_password,
  File "/zap/zap_auth.py", line 280, in find_and_fill_element
    element.clear()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 95, in clear
    self._execute(Command.CLEAR_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: headless chrome=108.0.5359.98)
```

Any suggestions about this case? once again my login page flow,  **Insert Email** > **Click Button "Continue"** > **(password field comes up)** **Insert Password** > **Click Button "Login"**

**UPDATE**

Sadly I can't afford the url due to private working website. But I hope this inspect element on this page would help. This is before continue button clicked...

[image: image1]

After I clicked the Continue button, the field will be unhide and button id change to login. In this link [zap](https://github.com/ICTU/zap2docker-auth-weekly/blob/master/zap_auth.py) is the source code and handler the login flow.

Comment: my experience is that, the field you are trying to interact with is hiden by an add or in a different iframe. hard to help further without the URL

Comment: Post the URL and the full code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. Sadly, I can't give the url since the website is private and I updated the info about the inspect and selenium code.